# ArcPy .replace Field Calculator - replace only standalone 0's with 111, not all instances of 0

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, string, replace

I've searched on google intensively, must be missing something here: I only want to replace (in a string field) standalone zeros (len is 1 character), but the .replace function replaces all instances of 0.

How can I only replace a single character (meaning the value is simply 0).  If the value is say 10004 or 02223 or 12450, leave alone.

[image: string replace]

Answer (score 3):

Use the Show Codeblock option and use this function:

```
def replace_zero_string(value):
    if value == '0': # assuming the field is a text field
        return value.replace('0', '111')
    else:
        return value
```

Then outside/below the code block section call the function like:

```
replace_zero_string(!rpuid!)
```